# UICollectionView Cells not displaying (MonoTouch/Xamarin)

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, uicollectionview

Working with a UICollectionView in Xamarin just as I have before but running into a strange problem -- When the view containing the collection loads, I see the cells for a short moment and then they disappear.  I double checked the ContentSize of the CollectionView and apparently it's defaulting to 0 width, 0 height but setting it manually doesn't seem to solve the problem.  The CollectionView seems to stick around (if I set the background color to black I see a black View in the parent) but the cells are disappearing

**Parent View (UIView subclass):**

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout layout = new UICollectionViewFlowLayout ();
layout.ItemSize = new SizeF (274, 281);
layout.MinimumInteritemSpacing = 3;
layout.ScrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal;

var haulCollection = new HaulCollectionController(layout);
haulCollection.CollectionView.Frame = new RectangleF (0, cellHeader.Frame.Bottom,    cellHeader.Frame.Width, 281);
AddSubview(haulCollection.CollectionView);
```

**UICollectionViewController:**

```
public class HaulCollectionController : UICollectionViewController
{

    public HaulCollectionController (UICollectionViewLayout layout) : base (layout)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        CollectionView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
        CollectionView.RegisterClassForCell (typeof(HaulCollectionCell), HaulCollectionCell.Key);
    }

    public override int NumberOfSections (UICollectionView collectionView)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public override int GetItemsCount (UICollectionView collectionView, int section)
    {
        return 6;
    }

    public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell (UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell = collectionView.DequeueReusableCell (HaulCollectionCell.Key, indexPath) as HaulCollectionCell;
        return cell;
    }

    public override bool ShouldHighlightItem (UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**UICollectionViewCell:**

```
public class HaulCollectionCell : UICollectionViewCell
{
    public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString ("HaulCollectionCell");

    public UILabel Retailer { get; set; }
    public UILabel Brand { get; set; }
    public UILabel ItemName { get; set; }

    [Export ("initWithFrame:")]
    public HaulCollectionCell (RectangleF frame) : base (frame)
    {
        BackgroundColor = UIColor.Cyan;

        var infoOverlay = new UIView (new RectangleF(0, Frame.Height-60, Frame.Width, 55)) {
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(255, 255, 255, 153)
        };

        Retailer = new UILabel (new RectangleF(15,10,100,22)) {
            Font = ViewHelpers.GetFont(20, false),
            Text = "DICK'S"
        };

        Brand = new UILabel (new RectangleF(Retailer.IntrinsicContentSize.Width + 10, 10, 100,22)) {
            Font = ViewHelpers.GetFont(20, true),
            Text = "Nike"
        };

        ItemName = new UILabel (new RectangleF(15, Brand.Frame.Bottom + 5, 200,30)) {
            Font = ViewHelpers.GetFont(26, false),
            Text = "Windrunner Tech Fleece"
        };

        infoOverlay.AddSubviews (Retailer,Brand,ItemName);

        ContentView.Add (infoOverlay);
    }
}
```

can't figure out exactly why I can't get the cells to display...

Comment: Have you read this http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/introduction_to_collection_views/

Comment: try using your collection view controller as the root controller instead of adding its view as a subview to another controller's view (`AddSubview(haulCollection.CollectionView);`), because that asks for trouble.

Comment: What if your application requires such functionality, Krumelur?